# Edit Record. Pass values of bound TextBoxes to View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a DataGrid which is bound to a ViewModel. When I select a record from the DataGrid, the TextBoxes (Username and Role) are displaying the data from the selected record. 
I want to edit the selected record but I'd like to check the data before it updates the list, hence the 'OneWay' binding mode.

I'm having trouble passing the values of the textboxes to the view model. I can get a value of one textboxes through the button and passing the value to my ICommand

```
 <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  Content="Edit" Margin="5 5" 
                    Command="{Binding EditUserCmd, Source={StaticResource viewModelUsers}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtUsername}
```

Is there a way to pass all the textboxes to the view model by creating a property in it that holds selected user? or passing the values of the texboxes to the view model somehow??

Thanks.

My view model

```
 public class UsersViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<UsersModel> Users { get; set; }

        private ICommand addUserCommand;
        private ICommand removeUserCommand;
        private ICommand editUserCommand;
        public ICommand AddUserCmd => addUserCommand ?? (addUserCommand = new AddUserCommand(this));
        public ICommand RemoveUserCmd => removeUserCommand ?? (removeUserCommand = new DeleteUserCommand(this));
        public ICommand EditUserCmd => editUserCommand ?? (editUserCommand = new EditUserCommand(this));

        private UsersModel selectedUser = new UsersModel();
        public UsersModel SelectedUser
        {
            get { return this.selectedUser; }
            set
            {
                this.selectedUser = value;
            }
        }

        public UsersViewModel()
        {
            // fetch data from db.            
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            Users = new ObservableCollection<UsersModel>(da.GetRegisteredUsers());
        }
    }
```

Model

```
    public class UsersModel
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string Surname {get; set;}

    }
```

Edit Command

```
  internal class EditUserCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        public UsersViewModel UsersViewModel { get; set; }
        public EditUserCommand(UsersViewModel usersViewModel)
        {
            this.UsersViewModel = usersViewModel;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
           // UsersModel user = (UsersModel)parameter;
           // if (user != null)
                //return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Id.ToString());

            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
           // UsersModel user = (UsersModel)parameter;
           // if (user != null)
               // this.UsersViewModel.Users

        }
    }
```

xaml

```
...
 <Window.Resources>[enter image description here][1]
        <m:UsersModel x:Key="users"></m:UsersModel>
        <vm:UsersViewModel x:Key="viewModelUsers"/>
 </Windows.Resources>
...

       <DataGrid  x:Name="gridUsers"
            Grid.Row="0" 
            DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelUsers}}" CanUserAddRows="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
        </DataGrid>

        <Grid Margin="10" Grid.Row="1"   DataContext="{Binding ElementName=gridUsers, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />

            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Label Grid.Row="0">UserName:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Path=Username, Mode=OneWay}"/>

            <Label Grid.Row="1">Role:</Label>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtRole" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Path=Role, Mode=OneWay}"/>



            <StackPanel Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                <Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1"  Content="Edit" Margin="5 5" 
                    Command="{Binding EditUserCmd, Source={StaticResource viewModelUsers}}"  CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=txtUsername}">

            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know that you can edit the `DataGrid` cells directly? You can even use [data validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-implement-validation-with-the-datagrid-control). This way invalid data cells get a red border and the data won't be committed unless the validation passes.

Another option is to let `UsersModel` implement [`INotifyDataErrorInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/silverlight/dotnet-windows-silverlight/ee652637(v=vs.95)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and validate properties directly. Then bind the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` to the view model and bind the edit `TextBox` elements to this property. This way you implemented live update and got rid of the edit commands:

**UsersViewModel.cs**

```
public class UsersViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<UsersModel> Users { get; set; }

  private UsersModel selectedUser;
  public UsersModel SelectedUser
  {
    get => this.selectedUser; 
    set => this.selectedUser = value;
  }

  public UsersViewModel()
  {
    // fetch data from db.            
    DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
    Users = new ObservableCollection<UsersModel>(da.GetRegisteredUsers());
  }
}
```

**UsersModel.cs**

```
public class UsersModel : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
  private int id;
  public int Id
  {
    get => this.id; 
    set { if (this.id != value && IsIdValid(value)) this.id = value; }
  }

  private string userName;
  public string UserName
  {
    get => this.userName; 
    set { if (this.userName != value && IsUserNameValid(value) && ) this.userName = value; }
  }

  private string surname;
  public string Surname
  {
    get => this.surname; 
    set { if (this.surname != value && IsSurnameValid(value) && ) this.surname = value; }
  }

  // Validates the Id property, updating the errors collection as needed.
  public bool IsIdValid(int value)
  {
    RemoveError(nameof(this.Id), ID_ERROR);
    if (value < 0)
    {
      AddError(nameof(this.Id), ID_ERROR, false);                 
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public bool IsUserNameValid(string value)
  {
    RemoveError(nameof(this.UserName), USER_NAME_ERROR);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
      AddError(nameof(this.UserName), USER_NAME_ERROR, false);
      return false;
    }            
    return true;
  }

  public bool IsSurnameValid(string value)
  {
    RemoveError(nameof(this.Surname), SURNAME_ERROR);
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
    {
      AddError(nameof(this.Surname), SURNAME_ERROR, false);
      return false;
    }            
    return true;
  }

  private Dictionary<String, List<String>> errors =
        new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
  private const string ID_ERROR = "Value cannot be less than 0.";
  private const string USER_NAME_ERROR = "Value cannot be empty.";
  private const string SURNAME_ERROR = "Value cannot be empty.";

  // Adds the specified error to the errors collection if it is not 
  // already present, inserting it in the first position if isWarning is 
  // false. Raises the ErrorsChanged event if the collection changes. 
  public void AddError(string propertyName, string error, bool isWarning)
  {
    if (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
      errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();

    if (!errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
    {
      if (isWarning) errors[propertyName].Add(error);
        else errors[propertyName].Insert(0, error);

      RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }
  }

  // Removes the specified error from the errors collection if it is
  // present. Raises the ErrorsChanged event if the collection changes.
  public void RemoveError(string propertyName, string error)
  {
    if (errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) &&
      errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
    {
      errors[propertyName].Remove(error);
      if (errors[propertyName].Count == 0) errors.Remove(propertyName);
        RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }
  }

  public void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (ErrorsChanged != null)
      ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }

  #region INotifyDataErrorInfo Members

  public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

  public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
  {
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName) || 
      !errors.ContainsKey(propertyName)) return null;
    return errors[propertyName];
  }

  public bool HasErrors
  {
    get => errors.Count > 0; 
  }

  #endregion
}
```

**View**
`TextBox.Text` bindings must be set to `TwoWay` (which is the default `Binding.Mode` value for this property)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gridUsers"
          DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelUsers}}" 
          CanUserAddRows="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser"} />

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewModelUsers}, Path=SelectedUser}">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Label Grid.Row="0">UserName:</Label>
  <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
           Text="{Binding Username, NotifyOnValidationError=True"/>

  <Label Grid.Row="1">Role:</Label>
  <TextBox x:Name="txtRole" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
           Text="{Binding Role, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks for the example. I didn't know you could edit cells and validate then in that way. Your example works fine however if the property is empty it will revert back to the previous value. What I've been asked is, to be able to edit the textboxes without reflecting the changes on the data grid, using 'OneWay' basically, but I cannot figure out how to get the values of the textboxes. It would be like to have a copy of the 'selectedUser' and check the data there. Once, it's checked, updated the  original 'selectedUser' to see the changes in the grid. Maybe check it in the 'CanExecute' method?

Comment: What do you mean _"if the property is empty ..."_? The new value or the old (current) value? The validation methods for `UserName` and `Surname` currently are just checking for empty strings by using `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. If you like to allow empty strigns then you have to adjust the validation constraint e.g. by replacing `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`.

Comment: The overall behavior is exactly what you expect (if I didn't get you wrong): 1. Edit `SelectedItem` of the `DataGrid` 2. Don't commit the edited value immediately 3. Validate edited/ new value 4. Reject if invalid or commit/display if valid. This is what data validation is for. Your way of editing a copy would also work but it is not as clean. You could also use a value converter to accept or reject changes. But to validate the property itself is the cleanest. It gives you the build-in mechanism to display errors e.g. by drawing a red border around input controls.

Comment: If you still want to stick with your initial approach (why would you?) then add a second `SelectedUserEditCopy` property to your view model and bind the `TextBox` to it. When the `SelectedUser` property changes create a copy of it and assign it to `SelectedUserEditCopy` for edit and validate this property. But it doesn't make any sense to validate a copy instead of the original.

Comment: The simplest MVVM way to get user input (e.g. `TextBox`)  to your view model is to use two way binding.

Comment: Thanks again @BionicCode. I'm new to WPF and the MVVM implentation and still there are many things I don't get. The idea behind is, if the user changes some values in the textboxes and these values  are valid, they would be reflected on the datagrid. But what happens if the user doesn't want to commit those changes to the database anymore and moves to another record in the grid? These changes will be still displayed on the datagrid. Can they be discarded? That's why I was thinking of updating one record at a time.

Comment: No problem, you are welcome to ask. Yes, you can do this. The common way to achieve this is to capture the `PreviewKeyDownEvent` and handle e.g. the Escape key. `TextBox` (`TextBoxBase` to be precise)  exposes `Undo` and `Redo` members you can use to handle the content. By default `TextBox` will update the binding (and therefore commit changes) when it has lost focus. The behavior you expect is the default behavior when editing `DataGrid` cells. Try it your self. Double click a cell and start to edit it. Then press escape.

Comment: I recommend to use the edit behavior of the `DataGrid` as it will more natural to the user. He will very likely click on the data he wants to edit and expects to edit it directly in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Your ViewModel should not know about text boxes - just add two new properties ([PropertyName]EditValue) and bind to them, then in your command check them and copy them to the model if correct or restore them if incorrect - This is the entire point in using view models instead of binding to models directly

Comment: that makes sense. Are you saying tho bind the properties to the textboxes? if this is the case, how could I get the selected value of the datagrid to show in the textbox? ' <TextBox x:Name="txtUsername" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,10" Text="{Binding Path=UserName, Mode=OneWay}"/>'